# Bind all client sockets to wifi interface

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-wifi

I'm writing a client application for my action camera.
There's an issue using network connections when smartphone connected to wifi and mobile network: Android determines, that wifi does not connected to internet, so all requests passed to mobile network interface.
I've already implemented the client API, that uses pre-bounded sockets to communicate with camera:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Network wifi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NetworkRequest.Builder requestBuilder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
        requestBuilder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        cm.requestNetwork(requestBuilder.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                wifi = network;
            }

            @Override
            public void onUnavailable() {
                super.onUnavailable();
                wifi = null;
            }
        });
    }

    Socket initSocket() {
        Socket sock = new Socket();
        if (wifi != null) {
            wifi.bindSocket(sock);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Warning: wifi network is null");
        }
        return sock;
    }
}
```

Also, i've implemeneted simple http-client to work with. So, any API request looks like:

```java
SomeCommandResult executeSomeCommand() {
    Socket sock = initSocket();
    HttpPacket res = API.performHttpRequest(sock, "GET /?command=some-command");
    return (SomeCommandResult) parseXML(new String(res.body));
}
```

But i've faced some problems implementing other components, so now i'm looking for another way to bind all sockets to the wifi interface (including internal net usage: ImageView, VideoView, etc).
I've discovered `Socket.setSocketImplFactory(...)`:

```java
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        Socket.setSocketImplFactory(new SocketImplFactory() {
            public SocketImpl createSocketImpl() {
                return new MySocketImpl();
            }
        });
    }
```

But i have no idea how to implement own `MySocketImpl`.

All i need is to intercept all outgoing socket connections and bind them to the wifi iface before connection actually established (force use wifi). Need help imlementing `MySocketImpl`. Or maybe someone have another idea how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [ianhanniballake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668081/properly-route-non-internet-wifi-sockets-cellular-internet-request-android-l) and corresponding blog post ([Connecting your App to a Wi-Fi Device](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/connecting-your-app-to-wi-fi-device.html)), now I know, there's a `ConnectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(Network network)` method.

So, this is how I've done:

```java
public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        NetworkRequest.Builder requestBuilder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
        requestBuilder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        cm.requestNetwork(requestBuilder.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                cm.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
            }

            @Override
            public void onUnavailable() {
                super.onUnavailable();
            }
        });
    }
}
```